# Is there a way to automatically initialize a variable if null

Tags: java, variables, null, initialization

I have this code in Java:

```
String foo = request.getParameter("bar");
if (foo == null) { 
    foo = ""; 
}
```

There are multiple values checked this way. In other languages I would probably be able to do something like this:

```
String foo = request.getParameter("bar") || "";
```

I was really just wondering if there is an equivalent in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String foo = request.getParameter("bar") !=null ? request.getParameter("bar") :"";
```

or if you feel like `getParameter()` calling twice, you can write

```
String foo = request.getParameter("bar");
foo = foo!=null? foo : "";
```

That's called [`ternary  operator or conditional operator (:?)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Comment: But here you call the `getParameter` method twice in case it was not null when called for the first time.

Comment: ah, yes, I could use ternary operator it's a good point, didn't think about it. thanks.

Comment: @Sva.Mu I'm on my way to edit while you are commenting :)

Answer (score 7):

If you use java 8, you can probably go with something like this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(request.getParameter("bar")).orElse("")
```

If you don't use java 8, you have the option to use the [Optional from Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html). Which offers similar API. For ex.

```
Optional.fromNullable(request.getParameter("bar")).or("")
```

Both of these allow specifying a function to create the alternate value as well.

If you just want to go old-school, create a method like:

```
static String emptyIfNull(String value) {
    if (value == null) return "";
    else return value;
}

emptyIfNull(request.getParameter("bar"))
```

Comment: If you're using Guava, you might as well use `Objects.firstNonNull(request,getParameter("bar"), "")`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I thought of updating the answer, but that approach is already in another [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32817980/1258479)

Answer (score 3):

Apache Commons Lang has the method `ObjectUtils::defaultIfNull`. You could easily implement it on your own using sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ's approach:

```
public static <T> T defaultIfNull(T object, T defaultValue) {
    return object == null ? defaultValue : object;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [MoreObjects.firstNonNull](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull(T,%20T)) from google [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) in order to not call 
request.getParameter("bar") twice.

```
String foo = MoreObjects.firstNonNull(request.getParameter("bar"), "");
```

Comment: I like the idea and the syntax, but I would need to import some library to use it? or well.. I'll go check it out instead of asking here :P